# Determining a serial protocol of an industrial crane

Tags: serial, protocol

I'm currently trying to read packets sent between a small truck-mounted crane's controller (handheld device with joysticks/buttons/etc) and its control box. The communication occurs over a single data wire, with no clock wire. I've successfully recorded traces of packets being sent under various conditions, and extracted the underlying bits (assuming unipolar NRZ encoding, which I'm almost certain of). I'm now struggling to determine what protocol is being used, and would love to know if it's similar to some industrial serial protocol I'm unaware of.

Relevant characteristics of the system and the traces that I've noticed:

- When disconnected, the controller sends packets, but the box does not send anything. There is only a small gap between consecutive packets sent out from the controller.
- When both devices are communicating, there is no gap between one's transmission and the others. That is, the box sends packets in the gaps between the controller's.
- The controller and box send data at two different logic levels: ~8V and ~16V, respectively, although the controller logic level drops to ~7V when running off the same power as the box.
- Baud rate is approximately 3000Hz, encoding is Unipolar NRZ.

There are some other oddities in the bits extracted from the packets, such as long sections repeated multiple times, but I'm trying for now to just see if there are known protocols that it might be following.

I've included traces of the standalone controller packets and the alternating box and controller packets. For reference, the units are volts and bit periods (1/bit rate).

Thank you!

[image: Disconnected: Just Controller]
[image: Connected: Controller (Lower) and Box (Higher)]

---

Edit: For a bit more reference, here are the bits extracted from one of the 8V packets when the crane is idling, without any input to the handheld controller:

```
101010101010101011111110110100001110101010101010101010100101010101010101111100110100101011111110110100001110101010101010101010100101010101010101111100110100101011111110110100001110101010101010101010100101010101010101111100110100101011111110110100001110101010101010101010100101010101010101111100110100101011111110110100001110101010110101010101011010101010101010100111011101010011111110
```

In hex:

```
aaaafed0eaaaaa5555f34afed0eaaaaa5555f34afed0eaaaaa5555f34afed0eaaaaa5555f34afed0eab555aaaa9dd4fe
```

Upon inspection, the message (384b long) seems to consist of a short header (0xaaaa), and a 72b section (0xfed0eaaaaa5555f34a) that repeats four times and then on the fifth repeat swaps to its own bitwise inversion at bit 27, before trailing off into some other stuff.

Other messages (such as when the handheld controller is being given input) follow similar formats, with the same header and similar repeating sections, although the repeating sections change contents and length (often to non-byte multiples). Sometimes every second copy of the repeating sections are bitwise inverted. This strange behaviour has caught me off guard, so I'm currently looking for any known serial protocols that do similar things.

Comment: Sounds like it is a proprietary communication protocol. Pretty common in industrial environments. I have done similar trying to decode something in the past (controls between a control pad and a CNC machine) and they made something slow and simple that worked for them.

Comment: Are you able to get scope traces at the bit level?  And any photos/diagrams of the handheld controller and control box?

Comment: Since you are controlling a crane, there will probably be safety features built in to the protocol, since an unwanted movement of the crane could cause injury. This probably accounts for the message duplication you are seeing, but there could also be a checksum or CRC on each message to prove its integrity. Not an easy protocol to reverse-engineer...

Comment: @jayben I'd expect you're right about the duplication and checksum/CRC.  But it's hard to say whether it's easy or difficult to reverse without looking.  A lot of safety-critical stuff is super-simple *because* it's safety-critical, and it's just a question of good trial-and-error to map the control-surface to the packets and whatever error-detection they might have.  If there's no signals to the handheld controller (ie no LED feedback etc) that will make it easier.  It may well be simple enough that it's just continuous Buttons X, Y, Z are pressed.

Comment: @jonathanjo Thank you for the help! I've edited the post to include a sample packet. I've made some progress with decoding certain sections of the packets (I've identified joystick IDs and values in the repeating sections), but the larger patterns are still an enigma. My working idea has been to try to find a similar known protocol to make things a little clearer, but I'm not sure how likely it is I'll find such a thing.

Comment: The next step will be to record packets while different buttons pressed, joysticks out of center, and so on. -- The sequence "aaaa5555" _might_ be a separator usable for synchronization.

Comment: Thanks for bits @Tom.  Do you have photos?  They really help.  If you had a photo of the circuit board othe handheld controller in particular.

Comment: Hi all - after a bit of pain, I discovered that the encoding is actually Unipolar NRZI, not Unipolar NRZ. This made the contents of the packet much clearer (I wa able to quickly identify the sections pertaining to different buttons/joysticklevels/etc.). Apart from that, my conclusion is that on the whole the protocol is proprietary, which mainly answers my question. Thanks for the helps all, especially @jonathanjo !

Comment: @Tom glad it's progressing.  Decoding a protocol is frustrating but when complete has a satisfaction better than any crossword puzzle.